# How to print local variable when assertion failed

Tags: debugging, assertion

Given the following code:

```
func[i_] := Module[{k}, k = i; Assert[k > 0, k]];
func[-1]
```

The output is:

```
Assert::asrtfe: Assertion k$250998>0 in Assert[k$250998>0,k$250998] failed.
```

How to let Mathematica output `Assert[k$250998>0,-1]` instead of `Assert[k$250998>0,k$250998]`?

Thanks.

Comment: `func[i_] := Module[{k}, k = i; With[{kk=k}, Assert[k > 0, kk]] ; k ];`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I use a custom function to wrap the `Assert` and it works.
`myAssert[test_, tag_] := Module[{}, Assert[test, tag]];
func[i_] := Module[{k}, k = i; myAssert[k > 0, k]];
func[-1]`
Also the strange number `$250998` in not in the output message any more.

Comment: Have you used `On[Assert]` to enable assertions?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise Mathematica won't print message like `Assert::asrtfe`.